# Factorization of differential equation and its solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integrable-systems

Let us consider the Korteweg-de Vries (KdV) equation. Upon applying the Miura transformation to this equation, it is reformulated as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}_1=\left(\frac{1}{2}u+\partial_x\right)\left(\dot{u}+\frac{3}{16}u^2u'-\frac{a}{2}u'''\right)=0.
\end{align}
The equation
\begin{align}
\dot{u}+\frac{3}{16}u^2u'-\frac{a}{2}u'''=0,
\end{align}
is recognized as the modified Korteweg-de Vries (MKdV) equation. A solution to the MKdV equation will solve $\mathcal{E}_1$, but the converse is not necessarily true; a solution to $\mathcal{E}_1$ may not satisfy the MKdV equation. This raises the question: Is there a method to map a solution from $\mathcal{E}_1$ to the MKdV equation?

This inquiry leads to a broader problem. Considering a specific partial differential equation $\mathrm{PDE}$, which adheres to the system
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}_2=\mathcal{D}\left(\mathrm{PDE}\right)=0,
\end{align}
one might ask whether it is possible to map solutions of $\mathcal{E}_2$ to those satisfying $\mathrm{PDE}=0$.